# Cordova needs ios-deploy version 1.9.2 or greater, you have version 1.9.0, but I have 1.9.4 installed

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I just started receiving this error using Ionic 3.  running the command ionic cordova build on OS 10.13.6.

npm version 6.1.0
ios-deploy version 1.9.4
ionic 4.5.0
cordova 8.1.2

Comment: what is issue on console?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your OSX I had the same problem but when I did my OSX update it worked.

Comment: I'm using a company machine and they haven't yet rolled out Mojave.